# FuelPHP Delete a Scaffold with CLI

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm using Fuel 1.2.1

I have used scaffold to create my CRUD with the following command:

```
oil generate scaffold news title:string body:text
```

Is there a command to destroy it, like in Rails?

edit: destroy argument would be nice

```
oil destroy scaffold news
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command does not exist. You have to do it manually.

DELETE:

```
APPPATH/classes/model/news.php
APPPATH/migrations/xxx_create_news.php
APPPATH/classes/controller/news.php
APPPATH/views/news/index.php
APPPATH/views/news/view.php
APPPATH/views/news/create.php
APPPATH/views/news/edit.php
APPPATH/views/news/_form.php
```

Comment: I also destroyed the news table and the news row into the migration table